# Getting Bootstrap accordion working in Wordpress loop with custom post type (collapsing issue)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, twitter-bootstrap

First off I am well aware that there is a plugin but I am **NOT** talking about the BS Short code plugin. I am talking about the actual bootstrap accordion. So here is what I am trying to accomplish, I am pretty close I am trying to use custom post types and fields to generate an accordion of questions. So I have a custom post type of "Questions' with a simple title field and a WISYWIG editor for the answer to the question.

**So here is my code:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'question'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php the_field('answer'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Please fill out some questions.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div><!--end of the accordion wrap-->
</div><!-- wrapper-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**The Problem:**

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
```

The problem is in that piece of code because each accordion has a unique id and when I loop it through the custom loop it displays all my questions fine BUT they all start off not collapsed and open because they all have the same id of `collapseOne`

How can I generate a unique id for each time WordPress loops through the accordion. (if I said that rite)

See how the accordion loads "Open" because it does not have a unique `href`, `aria-controls` and `id`.

```
href="#collapseOne"

aria-controls="collapseOne"

id="collapseOne"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I got it. I used `<?php the_ID(); ?>` to set unique id's but even so that was not the problem. Turns out the first accordion had a class of `"in"` so the real question was

`How can I only give a class to the first post of a loop?`

and I did that by using a simple counter. `<?php $c = 0; ?>` increment it at the end of the loop then give a conditional that echo's `"in" if c is = to 1`.

Heres the code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'question',
        'order'     => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php $c = 0; ?>

<div class="wrap">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $c++; ?>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse <?php if( $c == 1 ) echo 'in'; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php the_field('answer'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Please fill out some questions.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!--end of the accordion wrap-->


</div><!--wrapper-->



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a built in WordPress query property `$the_query->current_post` (first post will be `0`) without the need to setup a counter:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'question',
        'order'     => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="wrap">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse<?php echo ($the_query->current_post == 0 ? ' in' : ''); ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php the_field('answer'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Please fill out some questions.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!--end of the accordion wrap-->


</div><!--wrapper-->



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The relevant bit is `<?php echo ($the_query->current_post == 0 ? ' in' : ''); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try The code below. In your code, the collapseOne was repeated throughout the loop. I added $i as counter and set it as id and href link

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'question'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <?php $i=1; ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <?php the_field('answer'); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <?php $i++; endwhile; else: ?>

        <p>Please fill out some questions.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div><!--end of the accordion wrap-->
    </div><!-- wrapper-->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Didn't work, just gave margins in between accordions.

Comment: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

this should be

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

Comment: Yes I have done that, still nothing. They all start open with the same ID.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I got it see my answer if you're curious.